# How to optimize Pharah's fuel consumption?

Tags: overwatch

Is there a pattern of activating Pharah's thrusters that lets you stay in flight for longer? Both just the hovering and when combined with her Jump Jet.

Comment: What do you consider "in flight"? Not touching the ground? It's possible (fairly easy, even) to keep yourself aloft by rocket jumping and then using (approximately) half-second pulses to slowly drift down until the rocket jump cooldown is up. Of course, if you're doing this in a predictable pattern, you're an easier target for snipers and offense champs like Soldier 76 or McCree.

Comment: Why half second pulses? How quickly does Pharah refuel? Is there a delay? That's what I'm looking for in an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Mage said in the comments, half second pulses are optimal because it allows pharah's fuel to refill without falling too fast due to gravity's acceleration. Maintaining somewhat of a constant, but still slightly decreasing, height.

It is also worthy to note that Pharah's fuel is refueling as long as she's not using it nor sliding/stuck on a non-standable surface.

This said, you don't have much room to stay in flight if you want to stay unpredictable. Just make sure to gain the most height possible by using your fuel and jump before using your first "Jump Jet".

Comment: Don't forget to use the concussion blast to boost yourself. :D

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the first paragraph.

Comment: Edited it. English is hard when sleepy af :p

Comment: Why are half second pulses better than holding the button for it? Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way but it should provide the same acceleration as pulsing, unless the acceleration is not constant in its duration, being weaker at the start.

Comment: I explained it, if you hold the button you will end up falling faster due to gravity (while you have no fuel)